# Why is Jupyter only running the latest function call?

Tags: python, pandas

```
"""add getTime and checkTime functions right before bf.loc and after ifs"""
def deposit(person_name,account_num, dep_amount, method):
    bf.loc[person_name]
    if method == 'cash':
        bank_cash = 0
        bf.loc[person_name, 'Account Number'] == account_num
        avalaible_bal = bf.loc[person_name, 'Balance']
        new_bal = avalaible_bal + dep_amount
        bank_cash += dep_amount
        return new_bal, bank_cash
    elif method == 'check':
        bf.loc[person_name, 'Account Number'] == account_num
        avalaible_bal = bf.loc[person_name, 'Balance']
        new_bal = avalaible_bal + dep_amount

deposit ('Person 2', '8638-2732-9520-2549', 450, 'cash')
deposit ('Person 3', '2619-4117-9965-7335', 230, 'cash')
deposit ('Person 2', '8638-2732-9520-2549', 450, 'cash')
```

I made this function. I know I repeated lines but will create a function to store those lines later on. My question is I called this 'deposit' function 3 times below but only received the last line(second person 2). The first deposit and second deposit called didn't get print.
Second, let's say person 2 balance is 0. If I called the function twice, would the balance be 900 instead of 450? Output is 450.
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Overall, it looks like you think you're writing a `Class`, when you're actually writing a `function`. You should probably look up the difference.

Comment: There aren't any `print()` statements here at all.  Why would you expect _anything_ to print?

Answer (score 1):

Only the last line will auto-print in a Notebook. If you want to display all three lines you need to either `print` them, or if you're using a new enough version of Jupyter Notebook, `display` them.

```
print(deposit ('Person 2', '8638-2732-9520-2549', 450, 'cash'))
print(deposit ('Person 3', '2619-4117-9965-7335', 230, 'cash'))
print(deposit ('Person 2', '8638-2732-9520-2549', 450, 'cash'))
```

Or

```
display(deposit ('Person 2', '8638-2732-9520-2549', 450, 'cash'))
display(deposit ('Person 3', '2619-4117-9965-7335', 230, 'cash'))
display(deposit ('Person 2', '8638-2732-9520-2549', 450, 'cash'))
```

As for why the last value is `450`... you reset the bank value back to 0 every time the function is run... `bank_cash = 0`